# ASCII to decimal value

Tags: c, type-conversion, hex, decimal

Consider this below example:

```
char a  = '4';

int c = (int)a;   // this gives the hex value of '4' which is 0x34
```

but I want the result `4` as an integer. How to do this? Just a `Hex2Dec` conversion?

Comment: `gives the hex value`...actually, it should read ASCII value in hex.

Comment: omt c = (int)a = '0';  to convert from numeric to binary.  Note '0' is 0x30

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int i = a - '0';
printf("%d",i);
```

The char values for digits `0` to `9` are contiguous and you make use of that here as shown above.

Answer (score 6):

The characters that represent decimal digits are laid out in ASCII space in numerical order.

- `'0'` is ASCII 0x30
- `'1'` is ASCII 0x31
- `'2'` is ASCII 0x32
- and so on.

This means that you can simply subtract `'0'` from your character to get the value you desire.

```
char a = ...;
if (a >= '0' && a <= '9')
{
    int digit = a - '0';
    // do something with digit
}
```

Comment: Not limited to ASCII, but in *all* encodings that conform to the C specification. "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."

Answer (score 2):

USe

```
char a = '4';     //ASCII value of '4' is 52
int b = a - '0';  // ASCii value of '0' is 48 so 52-48 will return 4.
printf("%d", b);  //It will print 4.
```

Answer (score 2):

- ASCII value of `0` [in hex] == 30.
- ASCII value of `9` [in hex] == 39.

Hope you got the relation. To get the `character` value as `integer`, just subtract the ASCII value of `0` from the `char` variable itself. The difference will be same as the value.

For details, check the ASCII table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

As example,

```
char cInput = `4`;
int iInput;

iInput = cInput - `0`;

printf("as integer = %d\n", iInput);
```

Will print `4`.

Answer (score 2):

ASCII conversion to value for characters in ranges a-f, A-F, or 0-9 can be accomplished with a switch statement, as is used in the following function:

```
unsigned char convert(unsigned char ch) {
    unsigned char value;
    switch (ch) {
        case 'A' :
        case 'B':
        case 'C':
        case 'D':
        case 'E':
        case 'F': value = ch + 10 - 'A';  break;
        case 'a':
        case 'b':
        case 'c':
        case 'd':
        case 'e':
        case 'f': value = ch + 10 - 'a';  break;
        default: value = ch - '0';
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some clarifications about your statement

> This gives the hex value of '4'

by doing:

```
char a  = '4';
```

you put the ASCII value of '4' - which maps to 0x34, in to the one byte variable 'a'.

The action:

```
int c = (int) a;
```

is called casting. what it does is copying the value inside 'a' (one byte) into the value in 'c' (4 bytes). Therefore, the value inside 'c' would be 0x00000034 (the other 3 bytes are initialized to zero).

Finally, when you want to print the value, you could do it in any way you want.
printf("%d",c);
will give you the decimal value - 52, whereas
printf("%x",c);
will give you the hexadecimal value.

Cheers,

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <string.h>
```

#include 
void main(){
if(!strcmp(name,"Jan")
printf("wellcom Jan");
else
printf("Error");
}

Comment: Need better formatting